# call a method return bool(false) in nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, nusoap

when i call a method and var_dump($result) then show bool(false) why?
i change my parameters to example and 1234 for writing here:

```
require_once('../class/nusoap.class.php');
// Create the client instance
$client = new soapclient('sample?wsdl' ,'wsdl', '', '', '', '');
$soapClient->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$soapClient->debug_flag = false;

// Check for an error
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    // Display the error
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
}
// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('enqueue', array('from' => '+12345',
'rcpt_array' => '123456',
'msg' => 'hi',
'uname' => 'example1',
'pass' => 'example2'));
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per PHP [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) documentation the second parameter for the SoapClient constructor should be an `array`

```
public SoapClient::SoapClient ( mixed $wsdl [, array $options ] )
```

But in your case you're passing series of arguments. I'm not sure this will work or not.

Secondly while working with Soap calls with `wsdl` we can directly call the wsdl method like this as per your example with the parameters.

```
$client->enqueue(array('from' => '+12345',
'rcpt_array' => '123456',
'msg' => 'hi',
'uname' => 'example1',
'pass' => 'example2'));
```

Here is a simple PHP soap call [example](http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/)

Comment: i change my code like this but still have problem :

// Pull in the NuSOAP code

require_once('../class/nusoap.class.php');

// Create the client instance

$client = new soapclient('sample?wsdl');

$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$client->debug_flag = false;

$result = $client->enqueue(array('from' => '+sample',
'rcpt_array' => '+sample',
'msg' => 'sample',
'uname' => 'sample',
'pass' => 'sample'));
var_dump($result);

and get this eror:
Call to undefined method soapclient::enqueue()

Comment: what do you mean about remove nusaop ??????
every work i do i get thi eror:
Call to undefined method soapclient::enqueue()